# assert the length of columns in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The below code filters google spreadsheet based on the boolean expression below. Code thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/19043534/newaza

```
function DeleteEmptyRows() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const values = sheet.getDataRange()
                      .getValues()
                      .filter(row => row[9] !== '' && row[7] !== '' && row[6] !== '')

  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent()

  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
              .setValues(values)                      

}
```

Nevertheless, I am having an issue that some records are being deleted even not matching the boolean expression.
Is there a way to assert that the lengths of `row[9]` `row[6]` and `row[7]` in the sheet before and after filter-operation ?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Is there a way to assert that the lengths of row[9] row[6] and row[7] in the sheet before and after filter-operation ?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Google Spreadsheets have columns and rows, the length of a column is the number of values in that specific column. I want to check the length of the column before `filter` operation and after `filter` operation.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to retrieve the length of columns, I think that you can do it by `values[0].length` and `sheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn()`. I think that in your showing script, the length of columns is not changed, while the length of rows might be changed by the condition of `filter`. If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: Thank your for reply. I know that the length of columns is not changed, but for some reason, some rows are missing which should not be missing after `filter` operation. Can I built and IF-condition to check if the length of `row[9] row[6] and row[7]` stays the same before and after `filter`. And then add the values resulted from `filter` to sheet?

Comment: Thank you for repying. When you want to check the length of rows before and after `filter`, how about modifying `const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(row => row[9] !== '' && row[7] !== '' && row[6] !== '')` to `const orgValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); console.log(orgValues.length); const values = orgValues.filter(row => row[9] !== '' && row[7] !== '' && row[6] !== ''); console.log(values.length);`? By this, you can see the length of rows before and after `fiter` at the log.

Comment: Thanks you so much, the error indeed was in the boolean expression. and I have finally reached a better results for my use case!

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this? If that's the case, would you consider posting an answer explaining what the issue was and how you solved it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

so The Error was caused by the boolean expression! Nevertheless, @Tanaike suggestion helps to debug column length.

```js
  function delDups() {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const orgValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    const values = orgValues.filter(row => !(!row[7] && !row[6]));
  
    sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
    return sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
                .setValues(values);                  
  }
```